# Update DOM with responses from several XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am building a simple open source Chromium extension that retrieve some data from several urls and then update the DOM. I could find another way to do this than by adding the line to update the DOM inside the callback `http1.onreadystatechange`

My `XMLHttpRequest` requests were often stuck on `http1.readyState = 3` so I have added a 3rd parameter to `http1.open("GET");` to make the request synchronous like this:

```
http1.open("GET", url, false);
```

But I am still getting these errors:

```
results[1].join is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange
annot read property 'join' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.http.onreadystatechange
```

Even thought they don't prevent the script from running, I think this isn't the right way to do what I want. So here is my question: how to update the DOM with the responses from several XMLHttpRequest request? Let's say I need to retrieve and compare all the data before updating the DOM. Then is there a way to process all the data at once after we have retrieve all of them  (cf my comment on the last line)?

Here is the relevant part of my script, the full script is available [here](https://github.com/MagTun/French_plus_plus-Chromium-extension/blob/master/popup.js):

```
  var urls = [
      ["https://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/" + keyword, "vtoolbar", "morf_sound"], //best for plural
      ["https://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/" + keyword, "syno_format"],
  ]
  // for test set keyword to any of this word :  hibou,  tribal, aller, lancer

  var resultdiv = document.getElementById("result")
  resultdiv.innerText = "requete en cours";
  var results = [];
  var errors = [];

  urls.forEach((item, index) => {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              parser = new DOMParser();
              var ulr1response = parser.parseFromString(http.responseText, "text/html");
              if (index == 0) {
                   //retrieve the data needed, save then in a list and push this list to the main list result

              } else if (index == 1) {
                  //retrieve the data needed, save then in a list and push this list to the main list result
              }

              // update the DOM 
              if (results[1] == "") {
                  resultdiv.innerHTML = results[0].join(", ") + "</br></br>Pas de synonymes trouvés"
              } else {
                  resultdiv.innerHTML = "<b>" + results[0].join(", ") + "</br></br>Synonymes:</b></br>● " + results[1].join('</br>● ')
              }

          } else {
              errors.push(index);
              resultdiv.innerText = "Erreur: " + index + " " + http.readyState + "  " + http.status;
          }
      }
      http.open("GET", item[0], false);
      http.send(null); // null = no parameters
  });

// it would be simplier if I could update the DOM here and not in  http.onreadystatechange
```

Comment: This is not answering your question, but you should use the `fetch` API instead of `XMLHttpRequest`. The `fetch` API is concise and easier to work with.

Comment: @james The output is correct because I am using the arrays to save the result and then retrieve the data. So it's ok if the first DOM update is replace by the second. Yes I could append the data after each request but let say I have to retrieve and compare all the data before updating the DOM, then how could I do that (I edited to make this point clearer)

Comment: @Javascriptonian, thanks for this, I looked into it and the syntax is indeed easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute some code once all requests have succeeded, you can try using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) together with [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```js
let keyword = "beaucoup";
let parser = new DOMParser();

let urls = [
  ["https://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/" + keyword, "vtoolbar", "morf_sound"], //best for plural
  ["https://www.cnrtl.fr/synonymie/" + keyword, "syno_format"]
];

let fetchPromises = urls.map(
  item => fetch(item[0]).then(
    response => parser.parseFromString(response.text(), "text/html")
  )
);

Promise.all(fetchPromises).then(
  results => {
    // code in here executes once all fetchPromises have succeeded
    // "results" will be an array of parsed response data
    console.log(results);
  }
).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Missing  a `then()` for each `fetch()` response object to access the actual data